# Show previous photo on click in the left half of the current photo in Colorbox

Tags: jquery, colorbox

In Colorbox 1.6.0, by default, a click on the displayed photo means the next available photo is displayed.

Can I customize Colorbox to display the previous photo when the user clicks the left half of the current photo?

I know how to determine if mouse click happened in left or right half of div in general, so I considered implementing my own click handler. The click handler would call prev() or next() public methods. Though, I don't know where exactly to put my click handler, as the Colorbox default behaviour takes precedence.

The photos in HTML:

```
<a class="my-colorbox" href="..." rel="gallery-colorbox" title="First"></a>
<a class="my-colorbox" href="..." rel="gallery-colorbox" title="Second"></a>
<a class="my-colorbox" href="..." rel="gallery-colorbox" title="Third"></a>
```

Colorbox initialization:

```
$(".my-colorbox").colorbox({
    rel: "gallery-colorbox",
    photo: true,
    loop: false,
    transition: "none",
    maxWidth: "90%",
    maxHeight: "90%",
    ...internationalization...
});
```

Click handler - the idea is taken from this question - [Determining if mouse click happened in left or right half of DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685708/determining-if-mouse-click-happened-in-left-or-right-half-of-div) :

```
$("#cboxLoadedContent").click(function (e) {
    var pWidth = $(this).innerWidth();
    var pOffset = $(this).offset();
    var x = e.pageX - pOffset.left;
    if (pWidth / 2 > x)
        $.colorbox.prev();
    else
        $.colorbox.next();
});
```

The problem is that `#cboxLoadedContent` is not the right place to bind the handler as the handler is never called.

I believe this is the code that takes precedence (Colorbox - function `load`).

```
...
photo = settings.get('createImg');
...
if ($related[1] && (settings.get('loop') || $related[index + 1])) {
    photo.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    photo.onclick = function () {
        publicMethod.next();
    };
}
```

Comment: Show us what you've done so far.

Comment: Question modified to show the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the demo colorbox, I see that when an image is displayed, the topmost dom element (so the one that will get hit in click event) is:

```
<img class="cboxPhoto" src="somePicture.jpg">
```

So I would attach the event handler to this particular type of `<img>`.

```
$(".my-colorbox").colorbox({
    /* your options */
    onComplete: function() {
        $(".cboxPhoto").removeAttr("onclick"); //stop the default
    }
});
$(document).on("click", ".cboxPhoto", function(e) {
    /* your left/right handler code here */
})
```

By adding the `.cboxPhoto` parameter I am filtering the click event that happens on the document and saying I'm only interested when it happens to an element that matches this selector.

This is harder than it needs to be I've [logged an issue](https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox/issues/719).

**Update:**

The issue has been responded to and so if you use v1.6.1 then the `onComplete` callback will be:

```
function() {
    $(".cboxPhoto").off("click.cbox");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The handler bound for for .cboxPhoto selector is at least called. Unfortunately, the default Colorbox click handling still takes precedence. If I click on the left half, nothing happens from the user perspective (Colorbox shows the next photo, my handler show again the current one). If I click on the right half, the +2 photo is displayed.

Comment: In fact I have, but my handler is called after Colorbox default one, so it doesn't make any change.

Comment: @TomášPiňos actually, I think using the onComplete callback might be better for this. See my further updated answer.

Comment: @TomášPiňos Also, I realised that the way to unbind is to use `removeAttr` (if you check the colorbox source, you will see it is an inline onclick, it's not bound using jquery: https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox/blob/master/jquery.colorbox.js#L1016)

Comment: Now this is an excellent hint. Yes - onComplete callback and removeAttr is a working combination. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just FYI, I actually filed an issue after this: https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox/issues/719