# Detect mouse click within 'X' of right side of form input and simulate enter keystroke

Tags: jquery

I have a very simple form with a background image:

```
<div id="search">
  <form role="search" method="get" class="" action="https://www.foo.com/">
    <label>
      <span class="screen-reader-text">Search for:</span>
      <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Search …" value="" name="s" title="Search for:">
    </label>
    <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Search">
  </form>           
</div>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

The form is generated with a Wordpress plugin and can't easily be manipulated. The only way to submit a form is pressing 'enter' after typing text.

I would like users to be able to click the search icon (the background image) in order to submit the form.

Firstly I need to detect a click within 35px of the right side of the form. I've found a similar question here: [Determining if mouse click happened in left or right half of DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685708/determining-if-mouse-click-happened-in-left-or-right-half-of-div)

However, that code doesn't allow for a specific pixel width.

Once clicked the form should submit which I believe I can use the following code for:

```
$(this).closest('form')[0].submit();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can modify the suggested code as this:

```
$("input").click(function(e){
   var pWidth = $(this).innerWidth(); //use .outerWidth() if you want borders
   var pOffset = $(this).offset(); 
   var x = e.pageX - pOffset.left;
    if(pWidth - x < 35)
        $(this).closest('form')[0].submit();
});
```

little explanation:

in pWidth you have clicked DOM element's width

e.pageX is a X coordinate of click, but you need to substract the left offset of the DOM element.

Then just simple get the width of the left side (from place of click to the right end of the DOM element) and compare it to the desired value (in this case 35px) if it is lower then this value submit the form

Comment: Brilliant, yes that works a treat. Is there any way to change the cursor to a hover state over the 35px on the right?

Comment: simply use $("input").on("hover", function(){});